# SSIS Lookup transformation repeating values

Tags: sql-server, ssis, lookup

I am trying to retrieve a list of films from excel table and then in the lookup transformation find the missing genres in SQL table and add them. The result should be to add two new genres in SQL table which will automatically be given the id. Problem is that no match up lookup retrieves repeating genres.

[image: My data viewer]

Instead of adding just "software" and "the dark side" he add 3 time "software". Can i somehow do distinct in lookup?

Comment: Is there a problem here?  Your image shows 4 different rows all being returned with 1 `Genre` value.  I think you are perhaps misunderstanding what the `Lookup` function does and how it works?

Comment: I need to add 1x Software and the dark side to sql table. Not 3 times software

Comment: I have 2 columna in sql: GenreId and GenreName. So i m adding software and the dark side as new genrenames and auto generate genreid with next available numbers

Comment: Why not add a sort prior to updating the table and use the Sorts "drop duplicate" facility?

Comment: I will try with this, new to ssis so i didnt know i can do with sort, thanks

Comment: Yeah it work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As @MiguelH posted, using Sort "drop duplicate" facility solved my problem.